# Cannot find module './[filename].jpeg' in production MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Im trying to serve images that uploaded in react but Im getting a module not found.
I have use react-app-rewire and customize-cra to get images outside of src/
this works in development even If i change the image multiple times but not in production Im getting

```
  Cannot find module './user-5f82366183d6073044f6d747-1603576187144.jpeg
```

maybe Im not serving the images right

```
... In react app
  const userPhoto = user && isAuthenticated ? user.photo : "default.jpg";
...

...
          <figure className="w-12 h-12 mr-4 overflow-hidden border-2 rounded-full">
            <img
              src={require(`../../../../../public/users/${userPhoto}`)}
              alt="your avatar"
              className="object-cover w-full h-full"
            />
          </figure>
...

...In my server

// Serve static assets in production MUST BELOW ALL THE ROUTES
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
  );
} else {
  // Serving static files in dev
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/src")));
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite approach when loading images from public folder:

```html
<img src={window.location.origin + '/users/' + userPhoto} />
```

#### EDIT

If it's working only in production ( then there is something wrong on how you serve your files in `dev` and you should revise it. You can't afford to have different behavior in `dev` from `prod`. It will be very hard for you to reproduce a bug in production for example!)

#### Easy solution for your case:

```
const userPhotoSrc = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" 
? window.location.origin + '/users/' + userPhoto 
: require('../../../../../public/users/' + userPhoto)

<img src={userPhotoSrc} />
```

Comment: that works in production, very nice, but not in development since your running 2 local servers, 1 for backend and 1 for frontend.